# DSN less ODBC Connection iSeries

Tags: vba, db2, odbc, ms-access-2010, ibm-midrange

I've hit a bit of a wall with a current project. I have a Access 2010 32-bit database that is linked via ODBC to an IBM iSeries. This application runs various checks and needs to update a table. It works fine when I use it on my PC with a System DSN connection. However, this is going to be deployed to a user and I have instructions to hard code in VBA the connection.

My db as 6 tables and so far I have the following in an AutoExec module:

(I've X'd out any sensitive info)

==================================

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Type TableDetails
TableName As String
SourceTableName As String
Attributes As Long
IndexSQL As String
Description As Variant
End Type


Public Function IBM()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim MinConStr As String
Dim S As String
Dim uid As String
Dim pwd As String

'You can use a full or partial connect string.

'Minimum connect string requires DRIVER and SYSTEM keywords.
'All other values default to the same value as a new data source.
'MinConStr = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=X.X.X.X;"
'cn.Open MinConStr
'cn.Close

'Full connect string
'NOTE: Connect strings should be verified after each CA version upgrade
S = "DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;"
S = S & "MGDSN = 0;"
S = S & "SEARCHPATTERN = 1;"
S = S & "ALLOWUNSCHAR = 0;"
S = S & "COMPRESSION = 0;"
S = S & "MAXFIELDLEN = 32;"
S = S & "SIGNON = 3;"
S = S & "SSL = 2;"
S = S & "SORTWEIGHT = 0;"
S = S & "LANGUAGEID = ENU;"
S = S & "DFTPKGLIB = QGPL;"
S = S & "PREFETCH = 0;"
S = S & "SORTTYPE = 0;"
S = S & "CONNTYPE = 0;"
S = S & "REMARKS = 0;"
S = S & "LIBVIEW = 0;"
S = S & "LAZYCLOSE = 1;"
S = S & "TRANSLATE = 0;"
S = S & "SCROLLABLE = 0;"
S = S & "BLOCKSIZE = 32;"
S = S & "RECBLOCK = 2;"
S = S & "XDYNAMIC = 1;"
S = S & "DEC = 0;"
S = S & "TSP = 0;"
S = S & "TFT = 0;"
S = S & "DSP = 1;"
S = S & "DFT = 5;"
S = S & "NAM = 0;"
S = S & "DBQ = DDILLING;"
S = S & "CMT = 0;"
S = S & "System = x.x.x.x;"

'UID and PWD can be passed in the connect string or on the open. This example passes them on the open.
S = S & "UID=xxxxxx;" 'optional
S = S & "PWD=xxxxxx;" 'optional

cn.Open S, uid, pwd
'cn.Close

'Or build and distribute a file dsn with the application. Use ODBC administrator to create the file dsn text file.
'cn.Open "File Name=C:\mydsn.dsn"
'cn.Close


'Another option is to build the datasource in your install
' - Use the ODBC Installer C APIs. VB Example (mnuCreateDSN_Click) is shown below.
' - Use the DAO DBEngine's RegisterDatabase method
' - Create the registry key (not recommended)

For Each varLinkedTableName In colCurrentTables
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database"
strConnectionString , acTable, varLinkedTableName, varLinkedTableName
Next

End Function
```

==================================

When I compile though I receive the message

Variable not defined

And varLinkedTableName is highlighted in the for each statement. Does this mean a reference is missing?

Also, I'm not even sure if the above is the correct way to achieve what I want? Is it best to link the tables first using the system DSN then use VBA to refresh them manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Michael

Comment: I think the compile error means you haven't declared `varLinkedTableName`.  Do you have `Dim varLinkedTableName` (or maybe `Dim varLinkedTableName As Variant`) anywhere?

Comment: Per @HansUp comment, remove `Option Explicit` and you'll most likely bypass that error.  Best if you fully define your variables and keep this line however.

Comment: Do not construe the comment by @HansUp as an instruction to remove `Option Explicit`.   Asserting `Option Explicit`, where it is missing, is the first step for trouble shooting.  Indeed it is the first step for VBA competency.

Comment: With `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`, the 3rd parameter (`DatabaseName`) which contains the connection string with an ODBC link, should start with "`ODBC;`", before `Driver=...`